# Подгрузка контактных данных с помощью AJAX/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Не могу разобраться, каким образом при нажатии на номер телефона на [этом](http://www.gdeetotdom.ru/obj/living/msk/11780198462/) сайте подгружаются оставшиеся 4 цифры номера. На некоторых сайтах телефоны подгружаются с помощью AJAX-запросов, телефон приходит в теле ответа, здесь же я ничего подобного не обнаружил: есть AJAX-запрос, но в теле ответа ничего нету.

Comment: Такие сайты обеспечивают защиту от парсинга. Иногда даже очень хитрыми способами. Тут же, как вариант, приходит изображение, байты которого великим колдунством переводятся в байты цифр.

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное время. Я рассматривал такой вариант, но изображение приходит всегда одно и то же) Нашел ajax, который возвращает телефон, он почему-то отрабатывает до нажатия на кнопку, сразу при загрузке сайта, а код HTML страницы не меняет до нажатия на эту кнопку.

Comment: Может и так - чтобы в исходном коде не нашли полного телефона, а запрос маскируется.

Comment: Так оно и есть, при загрузке страницы уходит запрос на http://www.gdeetotdom.ru/phone/11780198462/classified/, а при клике, просто заменяется текст кнопки. Телефон в ответе сервера в открытом виде

Comment: @Petr Chalov, забыл сказать спасибо!